# Cardioid in motion of venus and earth

Tags: geometry

The following gif is a [motion of venus and earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP1aX.jpg)

[image]

How to prove that central heart shape figure is [Cardioid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html)?

Comment: Is it? Venus and Earth are not in resonance of any kind, so their orbital parameters are not nicely related to each other. I suppose this thing is but a superficial likeness of a cardioid.

Comment: I don't think it is a cardioid.

Comment: I suspect (but have not investigated) that if you treated the orbits of Earth and Venus as coplanar concentric circles, that it would indeed be a cartioid, regardless of resonances. However with the actual orbits, it only approximates a cartioid because the planes are close to the same, and both orbits are close to circular.